# Spring Framework - root-context.xml FileNotFoundException?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filenotfoundexception, applicationcontext

I am using SpringSource suit 2.9.2 and a newbie in Spring MVC world. I am trying to get an hold over object of Application Context using the following code: -

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");
UsersDaoImpl usersDao = context.getBean("usersDaoImpl", UsersDaoImpl.class);
Users user = usersDao.getUsers(name);
return user;
```

And its returning me `FileNotFoundException` exception. I tried different paths as well for ex. `spring/root-context.xml` etc. but nothing seems to work. Here is a stack trace: -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    com.varundroid.demos.HomeController.testingDatabase(HomeController.java:65)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: where is your **root-context.xml** ?? `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");` - for this statement to work, you need to have **root-context.xml** in classpath i.e. src

Comment: It is created by SpringSource Suite at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml. I tried to create a new definition file as well called spring.xml which resides parallel to src folder but i am still getting the same Exception.

Comment: Not parallel. It must be src/spring.xml

Comment: Tried that as well. I uploaded an image of my file structure, take a look at it, may be you'll find what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question here is why do you need to create new application context in web application instead of using the existing ones.

As far as I can see from your setup, you should have `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` declared in your `web.xml`. If so, you need to access context loaded by these classes rather than to create a new one.

If you want to access `ApplicationContext` inside a Spring bean, you can use [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) or autowiring. If you want to do it outside of Spring bean (for example, in `Servlet` or `Filter`), you can use [`WebApplicationContextUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html).

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to access `ApplicationContext` in this case. If you want to inject one Spring bean (DAO) into another one (controller), you can use autowiring:

```
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
```

Also note that if `UserDaoImpl` is a class that implements `UserDao` interface it would be better to use interface when declaring dependency.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the real issue. I have updated my code. Can you please take a look and tell me is there any alternative to the procedure of getting an hold over instance of DaoImpl using ApplicationContextAware?? And i am using Autowired in my UsersDaoImpl.java to get data source from root-context.xml.

Comment: Where do you want to get `UsersDaoImpl`? Anyway, you shouldn't create new context, you should use the existing one.

Comment: In my HomeController class. I am new to Spring framework and using a default file structure provided by SpringSource suite. Can you tell me how to get an hold of existing ApplicationObject?

Comment: i am having a strange issue can you please take a look.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360273/springhibernate-having-trouble-calling-persist

Answer (score 2):

Chances are Spring cant find it in your class path.

Put that file under /src/main/resources (as shown in your image).

PS : That's my general practice and it has never failed till now. 

Refer the image, here my context file is `application-web-context.xml`

[image]